# Given $f(x)$ is continuous on [-1, 1], prove that $\lim_{h \to 0} \int^{1}_{-1} \frac{h}{h^2+x^2} f(x) dx = \pi f(0)$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

My attempt at solution is as follows:

> $$\begin{align} \int^{1}_{-1}\frac{h}{h^2+x^2}f(x)dx &=\int^{0}_{-1}\frac{h}{h^2+x^2}f(x)dx+\int^{1}_{-1}\frac{h}{h^2+x^2}f(x)dx \\ &= f(\xi_1)\int^{0}_{-1}\frac{h}{h^2+x^2}dx+f(\xi_2)\int^{1}_{0}\frac{h}{h^2+x^2}dx \\ &=f(\xi_1)\{\arctan(0)-\arctan(\frac{-1}{h})\}+f(\xi_2)\{\arctan(\frac{1}{h})-\arctan(0)\} \\ &=\arctan(\frac{1}{h})\{f(\xi_1)+f(\xi_2)\} \end{align}$$
> Now, taking the limit of both sides as $h \to 0$:
> $$\lim_{h\to0} \int^{1}_{-1}\frac{h}{h^2+x^2}f(x)dx = \frac{\pi}{2}\{f(\xi_1)+f(\xi_2)\}$$

However, I have no idea how to proceed after this point. I would like to get some hints/ideas on how to proceed.

Comment: Use the substitution $x=hy$

Comment: At what point @NinadMunshi? I already used the substitution x = ht to compute $\int^{0}_{-1}\frac{h}{h^2+x^2}dx$ and obtain $\arctan(\frac{x}{h})$

Comment: Before you removed the functions $f$, it should have been your very first step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int^{1}_{-1}\frac{h}{h^2+x^2}f(x)dx & = \frac{1}{h}\int^{1}_{-1}\frac{f(x)}{1+(x/h)^2} \ dx  \\
 &  = \int_{-1/h}^{1/h} \frac{f(hu)}{1+u^2} du \\
& =  \int_{\infty}^{\infty} \chi_{[-1/h, 1/h]}\frac{f(hu)}{1+u^2} du 
\end{align}

The integrand is dominated by $\frac{\max\{f(x)\}}{1+u^2}$ so you can interchange limit $h \to 0$ with the integral to get

$$f(0) \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+u^2} du = \pi f(0) $$

Comment: Can you clarify what $\chi_{[-1/h, 1/h]}$ refers to?

Comment: This is the characteristic function on $ [-1/h, 1/h]$. So it's the function equal to $1$ on  $ [-1/h, 1/h]$ and $0$ elsewhere.

Comment: How is the integral dominated by $|f|$? You don't have $|f(hu)|\le |f(u)|$

Comment: @ArcticChar True. I guess it's dominated by $\frac{\max f}{1+u^2} $